# Term for the saline equilibrium of the body?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, biology

There is a term for the balanced percentage level of salt in the body, but I can't remember what it is. It is not eutectic, but it is a word like that. The X level of salts in the human body is 0.9%.

Comment: While this isn't entirely off-topic here, a better site would be [biology.se].

Comment: Could you provide a more appropriate example sentence please. The one provided does not need your "X", or a suitable word to replace it would be "normal". Also, a minor point, it is more precise scientifically to talk about concentrations rather than levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term is [isotonic](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/isotonic).

> Denoting or relating to a solution having the same osmotic pressure as some other solution, especially one in a cell or a body fluid.

Comment: This may be the word the poster was thinking of, but it doesn't work for me in his example sentence. Perhaps it is the question, not the answer.

Comment: @David: The noun form is isotonicity.

Comment: I wasn’t being clear. The term isotonic doesn’t have any intrinsic meaning that indicates a relation to the human body, but its long-standing use to describe saline used clinically — isotonic saline — is comprehensible as “saline isotonic with body fluids. Fine. However as a scientist and lover of plain English I would say that replacing X by “isotonic” is superfluous and inappropriate usage. You can say “The level of salts in the human body …” (omitting X) or “The normal level of salts…” or “The drip we are giving the patient is isotonic” (rather than hypotonic). The poster should take care.